# How to properly unit test parcelable objects?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I am wondering what the best way to unit test Android parcelable objects is. I know how I can test parcelable objects using the `Parcel.obtain()` and writing it to a parcel and creating it using the creator. The problem with this method is it will not catch if someone adds a field to an object without adding it to the parcelable/equals/hashcode logic. Is there a library or method that exists to confirm that all object fields are written to a parcel? I know that not all fields should be parceled, I envision an annotation or something per field to determine if should be included in the unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

In your `build.gradle`:

```
testCompile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
```

You can then specify which fields to ignore or make it ignore [transient](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient) fields

```
User one = new User();
one.setName("Salem")
one.setLastName("Saberhagen");
one.setAddress("Somewhere");
one.setAge(1000);

User two = one.clone();
two.setAddress("Mars");
two.setAge(2000);

reflectionEquals(one, two); // -> False
reflectionEquals(one, two, "address", "age"); // -> True
```